# Replace different Values in String?

Tags: javascript

I have a string which looks like this: `(id:561644cdb40fbe0100247dd7:q) (id:56165d8a79c8c40100adbdb6:q)` and I need to replace the different id's with different values. I already have the id's in a variable and trying to loop through with something like this `var mailId = "(id:" + rplcId + ":q)";` But If I use the `replace()` function it doesnt work...Any other suggestions?

Comment: Show what you have coded, what progress you made and what error you got, instead of just saying "doesn't work".

Answer (score 1):

You can select the id with:

```
"(id:56165d8a79c8c40100adbdb6:q)".split(":")[1]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var id = "(id:561644cdb40fbe0100247dd7:q)";
var idArr = id.split(":");
idArr[1] = newId; //56165d8a79c8c40100adbdb6
var mailId = idArr[0]+idArr[1]+idArr[2];
```

and please provide your full code